# Junit test for mapstruct object

Tags: junit, junit5, mapstruct

I've created a unit test where I have a `PersonMapper` that uses `PetMapper` and `WorkMapper`, and at the end, in my code, I'm using the mapstrcut generated classes instead of the interfaces that I've created.

The code below represents my unit test:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {PersonMapperImpl.class, PetMapperImpl.class, WorkMapperImpl.class})
public class PersonMapperTest {

    @Autowired private PersonMapperImpl personMapperImpl;

    @Test
    ...
}
```

My question is, I expected to use the interfaces, but in this unit test I put directly the mapstruct generated classes. Is it a good approach to test mapstruct objects?

Comment: Why do you use the implementation in stead of the interfaces?

Comment: Because If I use the interfaces the spring returns this exception: `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException`

Comment: Ah.. I suspected as much.. check out: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/blob/master/processor/src/test/java/org/mapstruct/ap/test/injectionstrategy/spring/constructor/SpringConstructorMapperTest.java I think you need the @componentscan annotation.

Comment: Still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `componentModel` in each mapper class, I have added this property to the MapStruct plugin in POM file:

```xml
<compilerArgs>
    <compilerArg>
        -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
    </compilerArg>
</compilerArgs>
```

Then I just had to remove the property `classes` as follow, and everything worked fine.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class PersonMapperTest {

    @Autowired private PersonMapper personMapper;

    @Test
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using MapStruct with Spring then the mappers should have the `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`. This would create implementation classes that would be annotated with `@Component`. In order to be able to use the interfaces in tests you would need to component scan the package of the mappers.